# Auto Scaling AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

The docs for lightsail suggest that it can be connected to most AWS services.

Is it possible to have a load balancer distribute to different lightsail instances and to automatically launch new lightsail instances if I'm getting high traffic? Or is this purely designed for people testing things out, so if we want scaling we need to go the full EC2 route?

If this is possible can we also use Amazon SSL with the LB to force all traffic to these instances via https?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 29th November 2017, you can now use load balancer with Lightsail.

> Amazon Lightsail has added load balancers to its easy-to-use cloud platform, enabling developers to build scalable, highly available websites and applications easily and quickly. Load balancers can be launched in minutes, fully configured and ready to route traffic to Lightsail instances for a low, predictable price of $18 per month. Lightsail load balancers also allow customers to easily build and maintain secure applications that accept HTTPS traffic with free SSL/TLS certificates and intuitive, built-in certificate management.

See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-lightsail-adds-load-balancers-with-integrated-certificate-management/

Comment: brilliant news!

Comment: This deep digged thread from Jan, got an ANSWERED badge after 11 months by a "low rep" member, sounds like add. I would add an IF to AI for moderation.

Comment: @titus what do you mean "sounds like add". please elaborate

Comment: I am paranoid, overthinking a lot. Odds to dig up 11 months old question look like intentional searching for a niche. = ) Nothing more.

Comment: Nah, it's March 2019 and I just found this question/answer via a google search. If this question didn't already say that Lightsail has loadbalancers I would have come back here and added that info, as the 3rd google result is an Amazon help article titled "Lightsail Load balancer". Instead I just upvoted Sharuzzam's answer and left this comment ;)

Comment: Lightsail does not auto-scale, you have to launch new instances manually in advance. It will not do it for you. Elastic Beanstalk seems to be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, you'll need to use the "real" EC2.  Lightsail is designed for one-off servers.

Comment: Bah that's a shame. I figured it would be as much, but hoped where they talked about integrating other AWS services we could auto create VPS from snapshots

Answer (score 1):

What you might want is Docker deployed to Amazon ECS on Fargate. This will autoscale as needed and you won't have to manage physical or virtual server resources.